# Сумма Бинарного дерева без рекурсии

Tags: delphi, бинарное-дерево, дерево, freepascal

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть задачи поиск и вставка элемента в бинарное дерево, с этим вроде справился. Код:

```
function SearchTree (var p:TreeNodePtr; num:integer):TreeNodePos;
var tmp:TreeNodePos;
begin
 tmp:=p;
 while tmp^ <> nil do 
 begin
     if tmp^^.data < num then
         tmp:=@tmp^^.right
     else
         tmp:=@tmp^^.left;
 end;
 if (tmp^ = nil) or (tmp^^.data = num ) then
     SearchTree:=tmp; 
end;

function AddToTree(var p:TreeNodePtr;num : integer):boolean;
var pos:TreeNodePos;
begin
 pos:= SearchTree(p,num);
 if pos^ = nil then 
 begin
     new(pos^);
     pos^^.data:=num;
     pos^^.right:=nil;
     pos^^.left:=nil;
     AddToTree:=true;
 end
 else
     AddToTree:=false;
end;
```

Ума не приложу как найти сумму дерева без использования рекурсии, буду рад если кто-то поможет решить. Спасибо!

```
function SearchTree (var p:TreeNodePtr; num:integer):TreeNodePos;
var tmp:TreeNodePtr;
begin
    tmp:=@p;
    if tmp^.data = num then
        SearchTree:=@tmp; 
    while tmp <> nil do 
    begin
        if tmp^.data < num then
            tmp:=tmp^.right
        else
            tmp:=tmp^.left;
    end;
    if tmp = nil then
        SearchTree:=@tmp;
end;
```

new

```
function AddToTree(var p:TreeNodePtr;num : integer):boolean;
var pos:TreeNodePtr;
begin
    pos:= SearchTree(p,num);
    if pos = nil then 
    begin
        new(pos);
        pos^.data:=num;
        pos^.right:=nil;
        pos^.left:=nil;
        AddToTree:=true;
    end
    else
        AddToTree:=false;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, уберите лишний указательный уровень - ни к чему эти `@p, tmp^ и tmp^^`

Во-вторых, в `SearchTree` на равенство значений нужно проверять до того, как пойдёшь направо или налево

А сумму без рекурсии можно получить, используя обход с помощью стека или очереди.
Заведите массив узлов, в первый элемент положите корень. Поддерживайте индекс вершины стека, на каждом шаге снимая элемент и вставляя его деток (если есть)

```
 Stack[0] := Root;
 StackIdx := 0;
 while StackIdx >= 0 do begin
     Node := Stack[StackIdx];
     Dec(StackIdx);
     Summ := Summ + Node.Value;
     if Node.Left <> Nil then
        Inc(StackIdx);
        Stack[StackIdx] := Node.Left;
     if Node.Rigth <> Nil then
        Inc(StackIdx);
        Stack[StackIdx] := Node.Right;
 end;
```

Вот поиск

```
function SearchTree (var p:TreeNodePtr; num:integer):TreeNodePtr;
var tmp:TreeNodePtr;
begin
    tmp:=p;
    while (tmp <> nil) and (tmp^.data <> num) do
        if tmp^.data < num then
            tmp:=tmp^.right
        else
            tmp:=tmp^.left;
    Result := tmp; //SearchTree, если в FP вдруг нету Result
end;
```

Comment: Вы уверены что нужно убрать все указатели на указатель и взятие адреса, вроде так на FreePascal не компилится ?

Comment: Да, только сделайте tmp того же типа (указатель на узел), что и p, а не указателем на указатель. В `tmp^.data` разыменование не помешает (в Delphi его можно опустить)

Comment: В комментариях невозможно читать код. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте код туда

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то функция будет двигать корень дерева, то есть каждый элемент будет первым, а корень мы по итогу теряем

Comment: Исправил код...

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста addTotree

Comment: Новый вариант addTotree кажется верным

Comment: Проблема в том что это не работает. Как я и говорил корень теряется:с
Возможно дело в самом FPC

Comment: Нет, от FPC тут ничего не зависит. Где-то ошибка в реализации. Кстати, var в аргументах ни к чему, замените на const. Но я и не вижу, чтобы `p` изменялся в приведённом коде. Может, я неверно понимаю "корень теряется" ?

Comment: 1. Я думаю что `p` не может быть константой т.к. Она изменяется добавляя новые ветки. Основа констант неизменность времени компиляции. 
2. Когда мы присваиваем `tmp:=p`, то мы даём ему само дерево, он идёт по направлению (вправо/ влево ), при этом все изменения отражаются в `p` нам возвращает путь, далее мы объявляем новый список и всё по кругу
3. Проверил я это с помощью добавления элементов в ветку от 1 до 10, при условии: num-1 < num. Далее цикл прохода по правой ветке, элементов в ветке нет. 
Не претендую на правоту, сам ещё только учусь, в любом случае огромное вам Спасибо!

Comment: `p` это адрес корня дерева или поддерева. В текущей реализации он не меняется. const-параметр это вовсе не константа времени компиляции, это, если на пальцах -  защита от случайного изменения параметра.